# Solr creates new document instead of updating existing doc, then updates the newly created

Tags: json, wordpress, solr

I'm working on a Solr index that has been filled by the Wordpress WPSOLR plugin. The index has ~60.000 documents which need daily stock updating so we're looking to find a way to do this fast.

I tried to update some documents with a json file through bin/post but instead of updating the current documents, Solr creates new documents. If I then adjust my stock values in the JSON and run the bin/post command again, the just created docs are updated. The original doc just sits there unchanged with the same ID.
When I run a select query on the ID I get the original document with the old stock values.

This is the JSON file I'm importing. 'id' is set as unique identifier. 'PID' is a required field and '_stock' is the one that needs updating.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1377",
        "PID": "1377",
        "_stock": 999
    }
]
```

Sent to Solr by CLI:
`curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/update/json?commit=true&versions=false' --data-binary @/tmp/solr_import.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'`

There is already a document in the collection with ID 1377, PID 1377 and a stock of 275 so I expected that to be updated.

I tried Atomic update as well, but that gave a nullpointerexception

```
[
    {
        "id": "1377",
        "PID": "1377",
        "_stock": {"set":999}
    }
]
```

Solr version: 8.11.1

Has anyone succeeded in such an import or is it just impossible what we're trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you have a different data type for the `id` field previously when the original data was imported? This sounds like an issue where the original data has a different set of tokens that doesn't get matched to the new format being submitted.

Comment: @MatsLindh Unfortunately sending the id and PID as number values gives the same result